# Castalia for Delphi - what happened to it?

Tags: delphi, plugins

I'm not really a Delphi person myself, really. The last time I've seen the software was over 10 years ago in the good ol' Borland days, and only briefly. That's why this research is a tough one for me.

As far as I know, Castalia was a plugin for Delphi IDE, which added lots of features like: code refactoring, code metrics, syntax highlighting, code navigation and a lot more. The plugin was proprietary, however the part responsible for actual parsing of the Delphi code is publicly available (https://github.com/jacobthurman/Castalia-Delphi-Parser). And that's all I know, really.

The plugin had its own website at http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/ which now is pretty much dead. The most recent version of the page with any information was captured in the 21st January 2015 and is available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150121050708/http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/). There's no clue why the product ceased to exist, all the authors say is that "it's not currently available", whatever that means.

I've heard rumors that Castalia is now a legitimate part of Delphi IDE, however I can't prove it in any way. Is it true? And if so, which version of Delphi was first integrated with Castalia? Did Embarcadero buy Castalia out?

Anything on that matter is much appreciated. Especially links to valid information sources. Cheers

Comment: I think from Delphi XE8 onward that became integrated part of IDE. In XE8 you could still disable it. From XE8 you can not.

Comment: Quite annoying that I can't disable it too, as it's completely useless to me and causes random IDE crashes. I used to disable it for that reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Embarcadero acquired Castalia and integrated it into the product:

- https://www.embarcadero.com/press-releases/embarcadero-acquires-castalia-and-usertility-from-twodesk-software
- http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_september_free_castalia_xe7.html
- http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-january-embarcadero-acquires-castalia-usertility.html

Comment: They may have integrated tiny pieces of it, but "integrated it into the product" is not accurate.

Comment: Agree with @EKW.
I even would name it "cannibalization" rather than "integration". (Hope this offends no one)

Comment: But what happened to Jacob Thurman (vibes)?